# How do I exclude a single file from svn:ignore?

Tags: bash, svn, svnignore, rabbitvcs

I've got a directory that needs to be ignored mostly. One of its files is special and I want to include it in the versioning system. The name of the folder to be ignored is `hw-description`, and the name of the file that I want to preserve is `system.hdf`.

I can add the `hw-description` to the `svn:ignore` list using `TortoiseSVN -> Properties -> svn:ignore`, and it works properly. Even though, I append `!system.hdf` to the next line, the file is still ignored.

What is the way of doing that?

## Solution using the `svn` command-line tool

As Robert [stated](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70404306/10400598) below, I should have not ignored the containing folder. Only the contents should have been ignored via setting the `svn:ignore` property of the folder as `*`. Therefore, I added only the `system.hdf` file to version control and ignored the rest of the folder. Here are the related commands for it:

```
# Add the folder to version control excluding the content
svn add hw-description/ --depth empty

# Add the specific file to version control
svn add hw-description/system.hdf

# Ignore the rest of the files via svn:ignore property
svn propset svn:ignore "*" hw-description/
```

Be aware that the parent folder must have been added to SVN before running the commands above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not ignore the whole folder, I would manually add the one file to SVN and commit it and then in that folder add an ignore entry for `*`.

As ignore entries do not affect already added files the one file will remain as it is and other files are ignored.

Comment: @CaglayanDOKME If you want to automate things use svn executable on command-line for adding, setting the ignore property and committing.